# HTML with Turkish text not displaying in UIWebview

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a UIWebview in my iOS project where i am loading English and turkish content from a web service.

I wrap the html string with appropriate HTML header and then save that to file locally before displaying the contents of the saved file in my UIWebview.

Here is the code i am using to save and display the HTML.

```
-(void) prepareHTML:(NSString*) html {
  tableOfcontentsHashMap = [NSMutableDictionary new];

//   html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;charset=UTF-8\"></head><body>%@</body></html>",html];

html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html lang=\"fr\"><head><meta content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" http-equiv=\"content-type\"/><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=320; initial-scale=0.5; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=1;\"/></head><body style=\"width:500;font-size:20px;\">%@</body></html>",html];
HTMLDocument *document = [HTMLDocument documentWithString:html];
NSArray *headers = [document nodesMatchingSelector: @"h1,h2"];

NSInteger x = 0;
for (HTMLElement *header in headers) {
    NSMutableOrderedSet *children = [header.parentNode mutableChildren];
    NSString * hash =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"heading_%ld", (long)x];
    HTMLElement *wrapper = [[HTMLElement alloc] initWithTagName:@"div"
                                                     attributes:@{@"id":
                                                                      hash}];
    [children insertObject:wrapper atIndex:[children indexOfObject:header]];
    [tableOfcontentsHashMap setObject:hash forKey:header.textContent];
    x++;
}
NSLog(@"Final HTML: %@",[document serializedFragment]);

[self writeHtmlToFile:[document serializedFragment] onWriteCallback:^(id result) {
    if(result) {
        NSLog(@"FilePath: %@",result);
        htmlFile = result;
        NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

        [self.webView loadData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];

    } else {
        [Utils showMessageHUDInView:self.view withMessage:@"Error Displaying information" afterError:YES];
    }
}];
```

}

With the above code, the HTML with english is displayed just fine, but HTML with turkish text is not displayed at all even though it is loaded just fine.

I have tried several encoding tricks/suggestions, as can be seen in the code. But I haven't been able to get it to display turkish HTML string.

Any suggestions from here will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is all about charset . Use `ISO 8859-9` instead of `UTF-8` as charset in your `meta` content of `HTML` `<head>`

this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Turkish_characters) mentioned for turkish character set.

> Turkish computers may use character set ISO 8859-9 ("Latin 5"), which
>   is identical to Latin 1 except that the rarely-used Icelandic
>   characters "eth", "thorn", and "y with acute accent" are replaced with
>   the needed Turkish characters. If you are reading Turkish text in
>   Wikipedia, when you see these Icelandic characters they are probably
>   meant to be the Turkish ones (users with Turkish computers may or may
>   not see them properly). If you are entering Turkish text into
>   Wikipedia, be aware that the Bomis server identifies web pages as ISO
>   8859-1, and there is no way to override this, so even if these
>   characters appear correct to you, they are not properly encoded from
>   the point of view of a non-Turkish Wiki reader.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

From above answer, i was able to find this [link](http://www.katpatuka.org/pub/doc/content-language/tr.htm) which has the correct way to do it, in code.

I also had to save my file with `NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding` and use the `windows-1254` charset in the `meta` header.